# Git. Question about Local Cleanup using git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

This question is from Local Cleanup section of https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Let's say we start with:

[image]

Then we do

```
git checkout feature
get rebase -i HEAD~3
```

After the commands do we get the following?

[image]

I would guess we could do interactive rebase like this to perform operations like squash, etc to the last three commits of Feature branch?

Can we also do normal rebase like this?

```
git checkout feature
git rebase HEAD~3
```

What would the result look like after the normal rebase like this? I'm guessing it does nothing in this case.

I would guess the point of local cleanup is to clean up the Feature branch before merging to Master. Am I in the right track?

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase` and `git rebase -i` are two different solutions to different problems. In some cases, like this one, you will need both.

In a git rebase “the commits that were previously saved into the temporary area are then reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order.” You want your feature branch to be based on the correct version of master. To catch it up you’ll need to rebase. Once you rebase to master, your feature history will be the two master commits + your four feature commits.

An interactive rebase allows you to fixup, change the message of, or otherwise combine commits. This is where you clean your work commits before creating a pull request and merging. This is where you condense your commits.

Your workflow here will look something like this (I use commit hashes instead of HEAD~X because they make more sense to me)

```
git rebase master
git rebase -i <commit hash before the commits you want to edit> 
<squash, fixup, reword your commits if you want>
git push -f <origin branch name>
<create pull request or merge to your master, whatever you want>
```